# Is it possible to have a SliverAppBar be transparent when expanded and then take a color when collapsed?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any easy way to have a SliverAppBar be transparent when expanded and then take a color when collapsed when used in combination with a `FlexibleSpaceBar`?

I want to use the `FlexibleSpaceBar` so that my title will collapse when the sliver list is scrolled up and down

It seems right now the default behavior is the opposite.  If you make the sliverAppBar transparent off the bat

```
                  SliverAppBar(
                    pinned: true,
                    expandedHeight: 100.0,
                    elevation: 0,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
```

Then there is no way to control the background color when its collapsed.  If you try to give a color here, then when its collapsed it successfully has a color but it cannot be made transparent when expanded.

Comment: Best solution I can find is, instead of using SliverAppBar, use a regular AppBar in a SliverToBoxAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I ultimately solved this by keeping the SliverAppBar as transparent, and then placing a Container widget into it.  Then using a scrollcontroller listener, I would animate the color of the containers background color as a scroll is happening.

It was a painful process, but it is working flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by setting the `forceMaterialTransparency: true,`

from your code, then

```
SliverAppBar(
    pinned: true,
    expandedHeight: 100.0,
    elevation: 0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    forceMaterialTransparency: true
)
```

Actuallly, you don't need to set `elevation` and `backgroundColor` anymore.

[see the details from flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar/forceMaterialTransparency.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SliverLayoutBuilder` which gives you the current scrolled amount, then scale Transparency by that number:

```
slivers: [
  SliverLayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, constraints) {
      const expandedHeight = 200.0;
      final scrolled = min(expandedHeight, constraints.scrollOffset) / expandedHeight;
      return SliverAppBar(
        expandedHeight: expandedHeight,
        pinned: true,
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB((scrolled * 255).round(), 0, 0, 0),
        flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
          title: Text(Title"),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
  //...
],
```

I like to use `scrolled * 200` to keep the AppBar slightly transparent.